# Aristophanes’ Clouds - What's the Significance of 3ʳᵈ Place?

Tags: socrates, greeks

After 20 years, I've circled back to reevaluate the Clouds (motivated primarily by a learned hatred of lawyers, and government in general).  I think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clouds) does a fine job of presenting the work indicating:

> The Clouds can best be understood in relation to Plato's works, as
>   evidence of a historic rivalry between poetic and philosophical modes
>   of thought.

The work appears to almost literally poo poo Philosophy. [link to play](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Greek/Clouds.htm)

> Student: He was up on the roof, looking up with his mouth open,
>   studying the motions and revolutions of the moon.  Well, just then,
>   suddenly, right out off the darkness, a lizard runs by and shits on
>   his face!
>
> Strepsiades: Ha! Love it!  A lizard, shitting on Socrates’ face!  Good
>   one!

Is there a significance to the 3ʳᵈ place reception / grading that the play is said to have received?  Is this grading historically accurate, or is it included in the play itself?  I suppose the fact that Aristophanes was not sentenced to death indicates something...

Comment: Why do you think that there is a "deep meaning" in the comedy's original grade ?

Comment: "the fact that Aristophanes was not sentenced to death..." Why so ? The comedy is about Socrates, that has been sentenced.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA well, I found that the meaning in Plato's written reflections on Socrates, for example, were often hidden in plain sight.  I remember re-reading sentences.  Only upon a re-read, or re-re-read would I get the issue.  So, I suppose that's where it comes from.  I'm suspicious of the face value of any of this old Greek stuff.  Even now, living in the modern West, I find myself looking at a [1 oz Gold coin with a face value of $50 and a market value of $1,200](http://www.apmex.com/product/39598/1-oz-gold-buffalo-bu-random-year).  Capiche?

Comment: Not sure to understand... Agreed that Aristophanes' play is mocking "philosophers" : sophists as well as Socrates, and probably for A (or at least his play) there is no big differences between the two, According to Plato, A's "accusations" of *impiety* may have helped the accusations against Socrates: maybe. But I think that there is no "political" issue behind the play's grading and I think that there were no accusations against A.

Comment: All this is based on historical sources (more or less reliable) and thus has quite nothing to do with the (undeniable) difficulty of reading Plato's dialogues.